# SymmetricDS: keep separate auto increment counters

Tags: symmetricds

I have a cluster sync'd by SymmetricDS. I want to keep the ranges of primary key different per server. However if I change the auto increment base on one server it is reflected on the other servers. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?   SymmetricDS will allow and identity insert for example in MSSQL on the target so that the source id will match the target and not auto increment.  This will keep the databases in sync.   Im not sure what you are asking when you say you want to keep different ranges per server?   SymmetricDS does not sync the seed values for ranges, only the data.   Are you requesting a load with a create tables first by chance this would send the source definition from source to target and would adjust the target seed.

Comment: Using MySQL. I mean range of auto-increment base. So set autoincrement base e.g. to 1000 on one machine and 2000 on a different machine. But they always sync up

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved by increasing the length of columns representing these IDs at the central node. This increased length then can be used for a unique prefix per leaf node in the sync graph. I have solved the issue by adding my own implementation of `org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.writer.DatabaseWriterFilterAdapter` implementing the interface `org.jumpmind.symmetric.ext.ISymmetricEngineAware`. This filter is then packaged with SymmetricDs engine and registered with `symmetric-extensions.xml` file. The filter would intercept all incoming rows of data, check the sender and prepend a unique ID. Same has to be done for all foreign keys.

If such data has to be synced back from central to leaf nodes, then a reverse implementation has to be created and registered that will be stripping the prefixes before sending data to leaf nodes.

It sounds complicated, but it's really not and it works quite well once put in place

Comment: Hmm this is a good solution but I was hoping to not manipulate the PK. I may just switch to globally unique PK's in that case

Comment: That would be the most simple and correct solution if it’s possible